# Normal Distribution CLT Question

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I am working on a self-study question where

> A study indicates that the typical American woman spends USD 340 per year for personal care products. The distribution of the amount follows a right-skewed distribution with a standard deviation of USD 80 per year. If a random sample of 100 women is selected, what is the probability that the sample mean of this sample will be between USD320 and USD350?

I made two attempts to answer the question: one using normal distribution and another using CLT. However, neither approach has helped me achieve the goal answer of 0.8882.

***My Normal Distribution Approach***

> [image]

***My CLT Approach***

> [image]

Appreciate some guidance and advice please

Comment: Please correct the typos in your question.

Comment: As per your drawing, "right skewed" means "positively skewed", i.e. that the _right_ tail is longer and probability mass concentrates to the _left_ of the density graph.

Comment: @Glen_b I've corrected the question. Do let me know if there's any more corrections needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal distribution approach given is failing to take into account how the standard deviation of the sample mean decreases with the sample size.

The CLT approach is looking good until you evaluate H(1.25).  Draw a picture of the area you are trying to calculate and try to figure out what is wrong.  Would it make sense to say that the area to the left of 1.25 was .1056?

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I get the hint. Since the question states that the distribution is right-skewed, therefore, we can't assume that the left and right area are the same.

Comment: That's not the only problem with that approach! You have simply *got* to stop throwing random calculations at these problems until you reproduce an answer. That's not how to understand what you're doing. You need to consider how to do the calculations that relate to the question. So if it's asking about the distribution sample averages, and your calculation doesn't consider the distribution sample averages, your answer can't be right. Since your first attempt didn't deal with the distribution of averages, it's a complete waste of time to even consider it.

Comment: jsk's first paragraph above is pointing out that in your first attempt you're not dealing with the distribution of averages. You need to ponder the error in ignoring the difference between a distribution for an individual and the distribution of some calculation based on more than one individual carefully, because you've made that error more than once, *even after that type of error has already been pointed out before*. Since the two approaches must give different answers, rather than do both and see if one was right, *figure out which one cannot be right before you start*.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Glen. Will make more conscious attempts to improve my problem solving methods. I am confident I will be able to continually improve and contribute to this awesome community which has really helped me a lot in my quest of self-learning stats.

Comment: @Glen_b Im complete clueless as how to determine the Z-value for measuring skewness. I was wondering if https://sites.google.com/site/fundamentalstatistics/appendix-b is something along the lines that I can look into?

Comment: I'm not sure what measuring skewness has to do with the question here; you're not even told how skew the distribution is.

Comment: @Glen_b not sure if i am understanding correctly, but what I inferred from jsk's inputs is that I will not be able to evaluate H(1.25) using the Z table since it is a skewed distribution, whereas the the Z table requires the graph to be symetric?

Comment: jsk's second paragraph relates to the distribution of averages, for which you apply the Central Limit Theorem (*which says what*??). In which case, skewness doesn't come into it *at all*. The problem is that your value is simply *wrong* there. Take a look at what jsk is telling you again, and then do as he or she suggested.

Comment: @Glen_b I can understand that the skewness will not come in at all given that it is CLT, therefore approximately normal. So in that sense, if I wanted to find P (320 < sample mean < 350), I will then be able to derive that P(-2.5 < z < 1.25), which in-turn results in H(1.25) - H(2.5). But what I noticed is that in the question it states that n = 100, where this 100 is the sample size of x and not sample mean (x-bar). Therefore, this is where my  dilemma lies

Comment: There are 100 observations in the sample from which the sample mean was calculated. You need to know about the distribution of that one sample mean (not the empirical distribution of the observed value of the sample mean, the distribution from which the sample mean is drawn). A single random variable still have a distribution, you don't need a collection of them. What does the CLT actually say?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14186/discussion-between-glen-b-and-user1275515)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the support and advice Glen & JSK.

I'm managed to work out the answer which I thought I share with everyone (and also get some pointers if I had any steps wrong despite getting to the right answer).

[image]